# How to store multiple stdout results in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

These are my first steps in Python 3.4 and also I haven't been programming anything for a longer time..

I have a Linux operating system command which returns many but one result per line on stdout.

What would be the best option to capture these results for further processing? I think that ideally would be to store every result line in separate table entries. But maybe you have some better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the command via

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['command', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

you can do

```
for line in sp.stdout:
    do_stuff_with(line)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I still must figure out how can I modify the strings because I get some unwanted marks like "b'" and "\n'" in results, however the solution you provided is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @K-K By iterating over a file object, the lines are yielded, each terminated with a newline character(`\n`). That's normal. What `b` means in your case remains unclear, however.

Answer (score 0):

Direct the stdout to a file:

```
'some linux command' > output.txt
```

Then with python it's simple to open and manipulate:

```
with open('output.txt') as my_file:
    content = my_file.readlines()
```

You'd have to give more details about your command and output for me to give a more specific suggestion.

Comment: @glglgl I was under the impression he was expecting his command to run outside of python. Not sure if that's true, but definitely would be better to fully enclose it if possible.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not precise enough. Thanks for your help anyway. I use external command (Linux command) which searches for specific type of files in the file system. It produces as a result paths to files one by one. My Python program should capture the lines and process them. Thanks!